# ベイズ最適化した後の.res形式のデータの型の変更方法がわかりません。

Tags: python3

python初心者です。

今、以下のようなバイナリリソースのデータがあるのですが、

```
randomforest_cv_bo.res
[{'target': 0.7784212030131844, 'params': {'max_features': 0.930055846603754, 'min_samples_split': 15.28549923074499, 'n_estimators': 166.1393782636472}}, {'target': 0.7785257751009637, 'params': {'max_features': 0.8211760874650731, 'min_samples_split': 16.400614250497348, 'n_estimators': 111.92312397601592}}, {'target': 0.776748024491158, 'params': {'max_features': 0.8527202619237652, 'min_samples_split': 10.276640212585447, 'n_estimators': 116.17540832901375}}]
```

このデータを出力させるために、例えば、

```
print(randomforest_cv_bo.res['max']['max_val'])
```

としても、

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

となり、出力できません。targetとparamsを項目ごとに出力したいのですが、出力するにはどのようにデータを変えればよいでしょうか？（.res形式での変更方法がわかりません）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> targetとparamsを項目ごとに出力したいのですが、

[pprint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) を利用してみてはどうでしょうか。

```py
>>> res = [{'target': 0.7784212030131844, 'params': {'max_features': 0.930055846603754, 'min_samples_split': 15.28549923074499, 'n_estimators': 166.1393782636472}}, {'target': 0.7785257751009637, 'params': {'max_features': 0.8211760874650731, 'min_samples_split': 16.400614250497348, 'n_estimators': 111.92312397601592}}, {'target': 0.776748024491158, 'params': {'max_features': 0.8527202619237652, 'min_samples_split': 10.276640212585447, 'n_estimators': 116.17540832901375}}]

>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(res)
[{'params': {'max_features': 0.930055846603754,
             'min_samples_split': 15.28549923074499,
             'n_estimators': 166.1393782636472},
  'target': 0.7784212030131844},
 {'params': {'max_features': 0.8211760874650731,
             'min_samples_split': 16.400614250497348,
             'n_estimators': 111.92312397601592},
  'target': 0.7785257751009637},
 {'params': {'max_features': 0.8527202619237652,
             'min_samples_split': 10.276640212585447,
             'n_estimators': 116.17540832901375},
  'target': 0.776748024491158}]
```

Comment: 助かりました。ありがとうございます